# Innertag values using XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml

In the Xml below, There are 4 Rack tags. I have to get the sum of quantities of all power supplies under Rack(tag), where Selected="True"

My C# code is:-

```
 XmlDocument xworkload = new XmlDocument();
  private void btnRackCount_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
            Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
            dlg.FileName = "Document"; // Default file name
            dlg.DefaultExt = ".hpa"; // Default file extension
            dlg.Filter = "Xml documents (.hpa)|*.hpa"; // Filter files by extension 

            var result = dlg.ShowDialog(); //opens the dialog box to select xml file
            if (result == true)
            {

            }    
               I have to get the sum of quantities of all power supplies under Rack(tag), where Selected="True"
```

Comment: What is Selected.  In the statement Selected==true

Comment: Try this XmlNode quantitiy in xworkload.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//Interview/Rack[@Selected='true']")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following XPath to select power supply quantities of selected racks:

```
var xpath = "//Interview/Rack[@Selected='True']/Server/ModelDetails/PowerSupply/Item/quantity";
XmlNodeList quantities = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes(xpath);
int sum = 0;
foreach (XmlNode node in quantities)
    sum += Int32.Parse(node.InnerText);
```

You also can use Linq to Xml with same Xpath as above:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(dlg.FileName);
int sum = xdoc.XPathSelectElements(xpath).Sum(q => (int)q); // returns 10
```